# How to use DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL correctly?

Tags: directx, directx-11

I am having issue while drawing my cube on the window. I don't see any graphics on the window. I see the following warning messages in visual studio:

`D3D11 WARNING: ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed: The Pixel Shader expects a Render Target View bound to slot 0, but the Render Target View was unbound during a call to Present. A successful Present call for DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL SwapChains unbinds backbuffer 0 from all GPU writeable bind points.  [ EXECUTION WARNING #3146082:`

`D3D11 WARNING: ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed: The Pixel Shader expects a Render Target View bound to slot 0, but none is bound. This is OK, as writes of an unbound Render Target View are discarded. It is also possible the developer knows the data will not be used anyway. This is only a problem if the developer actually intended to bind a Render Target View here. [ EXECUTION WARNING #3146081: DEVICE_DRAW_RENDERTARGETVIEW_NOT_SET]`

I created `swapchain` using the following API:

```
virtual IDXGISwapChain* SwapChain(HWND wnd)
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
IDXGISwapChain* swapchain = nullptr;

DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC desc;
ZeroMemory(&desc, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));
desc.Windowed = TRUE; // Sets the initial state of full-screen mode.
desc.BufferCount = 2;
desc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
desc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;      //multisampling setting
desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;    //vendor-specific flag
desc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL;
desc.OutputWindow = wnd;

// Create the DXGI device object to use in other factories, such as Direct2D.
IDXGIDevice3* dxgiDevice;
hr = device_->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice3), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&dxgiDevice));
if (FAILED(hr))
  return nullptr;

// Create swap chain.
IDXGIAdapter* adapter;
IDXGIFactory* factory;

hr = dxgiDevice->GetAdapter(&adapter);
dxgiDevice->Release();
if (FAILED(hr))
  return nullptr;

adapter->GetParent(IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory));
hr = factory->CreateSwapChain(device_, &desc, &swapchain);
adapter->Release();
factory->Release();
return swapchain;
}
```

Render Target is bound using the call:

```
m_d3dDevice.Context()->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_pRenderTarget, , _pDepthStencilView);
```

The `Present` is implemented as:

```
swap_chain->Present(0, 0);
```

The shader code is:

```
cbuffer ConstantBuffer : register(b0)
{
  matrix World;
  matrix View;
  matrix Projection;
  float4 vLightDir[2];
  float4 vLightColor[2];
  float4 vOutputColor;
}

struct VS_INPUT
{
  float4 Pos : POSITION;
  float3 Norm : NORMAL;
};

struct PS_INPUT
{
  float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
  float3 Norm : TEXCOORD0;
};


PS_INPUT VS(VS_INPUT input)
{
  PS_INPUT output = (PS_INPUT)0;
  output.Pos = mul(input.Pos, World);
  output.Pos = mul(output.Pos, View);
  output.Pos = mul(output.Pos, Projection);
  output.Norm = mul(float4(input.Norm, 1), World).xyz;

  return output;
}

float4 PS(PS_INPUT input) : SV_Target
{
    float4 finalColor = 0;

    //do NdotL lighting for 2 lights
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        finalColor += saturate(dot((float3)vLightDir[i],input.Norm) * vLightColor[i]);
    }
    finalColor.a = 1;
    return finalColor;
}


float4 PSSolid(PS_INPUT input) : SV_Target
{
    return vOutputColor;
}
```

Comment: I think I may have found the issue. The link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dxgi1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgiswapchain1-present1 says that `For flip presentation model swap chains that you create with the DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL value set, a successful presentation results in an unbind of back buffer 0 from the graphics pipeline, except for when you pass the DXGI_PRESENT_DO_NOT_SEQUENCE flag in the Flags parameter.`  So I just need to set the render target again in my render method and it works!  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In general you should set your render targets, viewport, and scissor rectangles every frame, typically right after you clear the render target and depth/stencil buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets(...) before each rendering

```
// Add this before each rendering
spImCtx->OMSetRenderTargets(1, spRTV.GetAddressOf(), spZView.Get());

// clear 
spImCtx->ClearRenderTargetView(spRTV.Get(), Colors::Black);
spImCtx->ClearDepthStencilView(spZView.Get(), D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);
// drawing...

// swap
spSwapChain->Present(1, 0);
```